# Unexpected For Loop Behavior - Three.js

Tags: javascript

I created an array to hold my 3D Objects, but iterating through it to make changes is not working as expected. What is the difference between these two code blocks, and how can I change the for loop accordingly? `objects` just holds the 3D objects that are stored with the variable names given in the second code block. I just don't understand how these two would be different.

```
objects.forEach((obj, index) => {
    objects[index] = obj.children[0];
    objects[index].angle = 0;
});
```

versus

```
sun.angle = 0;
mercury = mercury.children[0];
mercury.angle = 0;
venus = venus.children[0];
venus.angle = 0;
earth = earth.children[0];
earth.angle = 0;
```

The second code block works here, but the first one does not.

Comment: What is the point of replacing mercury with mercury.children[0];? What is the desired object? And what do the original objects look like?

Comment: This seems like a potential reference issue. How are you populating those items into your array?

Comment: you say 'not working as expected' but what was the result of the first code block and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're wanting the assignment of `objects[index] = obj.children[0]` to change what the variable for the first planet points to, but that's not how object references work.  This diagram might help explain:

```
let moon = { children: [] }
let earth = { children: [ moon ] }
let objects = [ earth ];
```

In memory this looks like this:

```
earth --------> {   <-------------------+
                  children: [           |
                    <ref-moon> -----+   |
                }                   |   |
                                    |   |
moon ---------> { children: [] } <--+   |
                                        |
objects -----> [                        |
                 <ref-earth> -----------+
               ]
```

So `earth` is a variable that points to the object in memory, and `objects[0]` also points to the same object. If you were to execute the code `objects[0] = earth.children[0]` we would end up with this in the diagram:

```
earth --------> {
                  children: [
                    <ref-moon> -----+
                }                   |
                                    /
moon ---------> { children: [] } <-+---+
                                       |
objects -----> [                       |
                 <ref-moon> -----------+
               ]
```

You see that `earth` still points to the object it originally did, but `objects[0]` now points to its child instead.  I suspect that you thought that the following would be equivalent but they're not:

1. objects[0] = earth.children[0];
2. earth = earth.children[0];

The assignment in the first line does not change the variable `earth` at all.

This is because each variable (earth, moon, objects) is just a reference to an object in memory. The important thing to understand is the difference between changing a reference and changing the object it refers to. The following code example demonstrates the concept a bit more directly.

```js
let obj1 = { id: 'red' }
let obj2 = { id: 'blue' }
let array = [ obj1, obj2 ]
obj1 = obj2  // now both variables point to blue
console.log('obj1 is blue:', obj1)
console.log('obj2 is blue:', obj2)
console.log('but array still has red:', array)
```